# Approaches for retrieving variadic-type data out of a single-getter function

Tags: c

tl;dr: preferred function signature of a *single* getter func that handles *all* readable members of possibly different type of an object.

Exposing `struct` definitions from a library and using them in a program lends itself to being an ABI breaker when such struct needs e.g. a new member. Where it matters, people prefer on using function-based getters/setters. Having one setter function for each member however sounds quite cumbersome, and in fact bloats the symbol table of DSOs, so if such can be avoided, the better. That kinda works out for the setter part using varargs:

```
struct foo {
    char *name;
    int size;
};
int foo_set(struct foo *foo, enum foo_field opt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, opt);
    if (opt == FOO_NAME)
        foo->name = strdup(va_arg(args, const char *));
    if (opt == FOO_SIZE)
        foo->size = va_arg(args, int);
    va_end(args);
    return 0;
}
```

Given such an approach, what do people prefer for a getter?—After all, the type needs to be conveyed back.

```
/* Return codes reserved to indicate failure/success */
int foo_get(struct foo *foo, enum foo_field opt, void *p) {
    if (opt == FOO_NAME)
        *(char **)p = foo->name;
    if (opt == FOO_SIZE)
        *(int *)p = foo->size;
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, the program calling foo_get would need to know that getting FOO_NAME/FOO_SIZE gives back a char */int *. If this rule was broken, the library could definitely add a new FOO_NAME2 if the return type was to become different.

```
struct foo {
    struct qstr *name;
    int size;
};
if (opt == FOO_NAME)
    return -EINVAL;
if (opt == FOO_NAME2)
    *(struct qstr **)p = foo->name;
```

What other common ways (in single-getter approaches) are there that people use?

Edit 2011-12-19:

How about additional inline functions that, since they will be inlined or eliminated, don't count towards the library ABI.

```
static inline int foo_get_name(struct foo *foo, const char **pptr) {
    return foo_get(foo, FOO_NAME, pptr); /* possibly heavy-duty */
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that throwing away type-safety is a good idea here...

Answer (score 0):

As Oli has commented, you're sacrificing type-safety. You're also forcing people to muck around with memory buffers passed by pointer, which quickly gets awkward. Just make a single getter per public data member. That's an ABI breaker in terms of backward compatibility with older versions of the library, but it retains forward compatibility if you never remove a getter.